# Requesting multiple partials with link tag in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of users that has conversation and progress of their own. When I click a user on this list, I want to request and render both conversation and progress partials of that user.

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= image_tag("doctor/avatar.png", :alt => "user", :style => 'width: 40px', class: "img-responsive") %> 
    </td>
  <td> 
    <%= link_to patient.name, conversation_path(patient.conversation.id), 
          :remote => true, class: 'grp', :style => "font-weight:bold; color:#000" %> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

By the `link_to` tag, I am able to successfully render the conversation partial.

```
// show.js.erb for Conversation
$("#chats").html("<%= escape_javascript render(@conversation) %>");
```

However, I don't know how to request for Conversation and Progress at the same time. Can I make a multiple request from a link_to tag?

Comment: please share details in your question.  the partials for conversation and progress. the relation between them.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that @Burak.  Could you create a partial which renders the two partials and `link_to` that partial?

Comment: @Athat there is no relation between them. They just both belong to a patient.

Comment: @steveklein Then do I have to create a controller for that partial?

Comment: I don't think I noticed that this was using Ajax when I originally read it.  Couldn't you just add a line in `show.js.erb` to render the progress?  You could assign a separate instance variable in your controller (like `@progress`) if needed.